# Play custom animated gif while the shiny app loads

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to play animated gif in my shiny app while it loads. I have searched in stackoverflow and found out this package "shinycssloaders". But i need to play a custom animated gif while the page loads. Please help me on this issue.

Please find a reproducible example of a shiny app,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Complete", tabName = "comp"))),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "comp",
                                  fluidRow(
                                    box(title = "data", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", 
                                        collapsible = TRUE, tableOutput("tbe")))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  output$tbe <- renderTable(mtcars)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks
SJB

Comment: when the page loads at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, when the page loads at beginning and also when each page loads after uploading the dataset.